# Some websites do not load in all my browsers

Tags: macos, safari, google-chrome, firefox, websites

Some websites do not open in safari, firefox and google chrome. I have been trying for a few days now and it is always the same.

In safari, I get
"Safari can't open the page "xxx" because the server unexpectedly dropped connection. This sometimes occurs when the server is busy. Wait for a few minutes then try again."

In google chrome, I get "This site can’t be reached.
The web page at xxx might be temporarily down or it may have moved permanently to a new web address. ERR_RESPONSE_HEADERS_TRUNCATED"

In firefox, when I click on the URL from google or type in the URL of the website, I get this
[image]

I am not sure why it does this because the URL is not a document.

I am on MacOS big sur 11.1
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Do you experience this problem on other devices? From your question, it is clear that you have tried different browsers but you did not specify whether other devices can display these websites or not.

In order for website to displayed properly, the server (website's end) needs to set appropriate HTTP headers. Here is a [sample](https://www.researchgate.net/figure/Typical-HTTP-response-and-request-headers_fig1_242714677) of what those headers may look like.

When the browser gets malformed headers, it will not know what exactly to do with the received information so it will try its best. What will happen exactly will depend on the browser's implementation. As you have noticed, different browsers respond differently to malformed http headers.

As a general rule, there are several things you can do to troubleshoot:

- https://downforeveryoneorjustme.com/ - if you do not have another device, you can use this service to test if the website is available or not
- https://tools.keycdn.com/curl - or a similar tool - can be used to inspect headers; but the same can be achieved with Google Chrome - see [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4423061/view-http-headers-in-google-chrome)

Comment: when I put the website into https://downforeveryoneorjustme.com/ , it said that it was just me.

Comment: This narrows down the issue but some troubleshooting is still required. Do you have an alternative device to try this on, like a mobile phone? Try with cellular network (like 3G or 4G). What is needed to establish is whether your particular device is affected or your entire home network.

Comment: I tried on my phone using 4G first and then the same wifi as my laptop, and it seems to work fine for both

Comment: It could be a misconfiguration of Mac or even malware. You could try [Malwarebytes for Mac](https://www.malwarebytes.com/mac/) to make sure your Mac is not infected. Then you would need to check your network settings (e.g. DNS). In other words, you are looking for something causing issues between your Mac and your browsers.

Comment: I deleted the malwares that were shown in malwarebytes, but the problem still remains. How do I check my network settings?

Comment: As you mention that some malware was in fact found, I would try [How to repair a Mac disk with Disk Utility](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT210898). I think at this point the issue is nailed i.e. there is a possible damage to the OS so you need to look into repair the OS (and if that fails, you would need to reinstall it)

Comment: Just in case, I assume you have Time Machine backups (or alternative form of backups) in place

Comment: I used disk utility and performed first aid, but it was very quick and said "first aid process is complete. click done to continue." does that mean it is done? The problem still remains.

Comment: To be honest, I am not too proficient with OSX, so I guess you could either ask a new question about how to repair OSX or research yourself.

Comment: I checked again and itsays that the disk appears to be fine.